# How can I reverse the effect of screen rotation on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, screen-orientation

I'm creating an application where user can rotate his mobile but the image inside web page will rotate in anti direction so it will seems to be still.

```
var rotate = 0 - window.orientation;
image.style.transform = "rotateZ("+ rotate * (Math.PI/180) +"deg)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working several hours i created a solution that's worked for me. 
Find the change in orientation and add Angle to it
Here is the Code:

```
          var difference = initialAngleOfImage - Math.abs(event.alpha);
          if(difference >= 0 && difference <= 15){
              difference = 15;
          }
          if(difference >= 16 && difference <= 30){
              difference = 15;
          }
          else if(difference >= 31 && difference <=45){
              difference = 45;
          }
          else if(difference >= 46 && difference <=60){
              difference = 60;
          }
          else if(difference >= 61 && difference <=90){
              difference = 30;
          }
```